# call multiple middleware / arguments in one variable - deno oak framework

Tags: typescript, deno, oak

I have this code

```
const keren = async (ctx: Context, next: any) => {
  console.log('keren');

  await next();
}

const mantap = async (ctx: Context, next: any) => {
  console.log('mantap');

  await next();
}

router.get('/owkowkkow',keren,mantap,(ctx: Context) => {
  ctx.response.body = "wkwkwkw";
});
```

it work's good , but i want to use keren and mantap in one variable called onevar

so the code gonna be like this :

```
router.get('/owkowkkow',onevar,(ctx: Context) => {
  ctx.response.body = "wkwkwkw";
});
```

how to do that? is it can?

Comment: what framework is that?

Comment: oak framework , deno

Comment: you should tag it as such instead of express, otherwise it confuses.

Comment: thanks man , can't wait for other answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oak comes with `compose` middleware that will allow you to compose a middleware from multiple middlewares

```js
import { composeMiddleware as compose } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const onevar = compose([
    async (ctx: Context, next: any) => {
      console.log('keren');

      await next();
    },

    async (ctx: Context, next: any) => {
      console.log('mantap');

      await next();
    }
])

router.get('/owkowkkow',onevar,(ctx: Context) => {
  ctx.response.body = "wkwkwkw";
});
```

Comment: Updated answer with built-in `compose` middleware

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande There is one typo => imported as composeMiddleware and used as compose